# With Bluetooth keyboard, Bluetooth mouse movement is jerky on Macbook Pro

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macbook, bluetooth, tracking

I have a Macbook Pro 2,2 from early 2007. I've been using a [Targus Bluetooth Laser Mouse for Mac](http://www.targus.com/us/formac/default.asp) for over a year now and its been wonderful (except for the optical scroll). Tracking has been as smooth as butter. Then someone gave me an old [Apple Wireless (Bluetooth) Keyboard](http://www.souq.com/Apple-Wireless-Keyboard/4624804-EN/). When both are connected, the keyboard seems to work just fine but the mouse's tracking is jerky and mouse clicks are occasionally missed. Using the trackpad on my laptop is still smooth as silk.

Any ideas of fixing this or do I need a wired keyboard?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for having a keyboard connected, but my Logitech MX Revolution has horrible jerkyness when connected over bluetooth, even when it's the only device paired with my MBP (early 2007). Never found a cause for it other than the setup just doesn't work. The mouse works perfectly with my desktop, though I haven't tested any other mice (don't have any) or keyboards (don't have any) with my MBP.

Does the keyboard lag and miss keys too? If so, I might argue that the bandwidth is somehow saturated (shouldn't be). If the mouse movement improves with a wired keyboard, try that (also another argument for not enough bandwidth). Or select a wired mouse if that's more your boat.

Comment: I don't notice the keyboard missing or lagging in any way. I just tried hooking up a wireless Mighty Mouse and it seems to be performing just fine even when I have the other mouse connected as well as the keyboard. I guess it's just a problem with my Targus mouse and too many other devices? Sounds weird since it's fine as long as it's the only thing connected.

Comment: I guess its just this setup. I've looked other places and occasionally certain setups are weird. Thanks!